# How to create dashboard view in Odoo 12?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I want to create a dashboard view in Odoo 12 that contains specific data. Can someone guide me to a tutorial that will help me to achieve this or show me how I can handle a dashboard view?

Answer (score 1):

Below given official Odoo guidelines to create dashboard.

[Odoo Documentation for Dashboard View](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/views.html#dashboard)

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [tutorial](https://webkul.com/blog/creating-odoo-custom-dashboard/) to see how to create a dashboard in Odoo. You can also check the existing free dashboard modules in Odoo apps to see how it works and what all things you need to add. For example check these two, [HR dashboard](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/hr_dashboard/) and [HRMS dashboard](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/hrms_dashboard/).